# java.lang.Comparable<T> cannot be converted to T"

Tags: java, generics, equals, doubly-linked-list, comparable

```
public class DoubleLinkedList<T> implements DoubleLinkedListADT<T> {
    //Double linked list node class
    public class DoubleLinkedListNode<T>  {
        T info;
        DoubleLinkedListNode<T> next;
        DoubleLinkedListNode<T> back;

        public DoubleLinkedListNode() {
            info = null;
            next = null;
            back = null;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return info.toString();
        }
    }

    protected int count;                     //number of nodes
    protected DoubleLinkedListNode<T> first; //reference to first node
    protected DoubleLinkedListNode<T> last;  //reference to last node

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(o instanceof DoubleLinkedList) {
            DoubleLinkedList<T> d = (DoubleLinkedList) o;
            if(count != d.count){
              return false;
            }
            else{
                DoubleLinkedListNode<T> curr = first;
                DoubleLinkedListNode<T> curr2 = d.first;
                while(curr != null && curr2 != null){
                    Comparable<T> temp = (Comparable<T>) curr.info;
                    Comparable<T> temp2 = (Comparable<T>) curr2.info;
                    if(temp.compareTo(temp2) >= 0){
                      return false;
                    }
                    curr = curr.next;
                    curr2 = curr2.next;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

the problem is on this if statement, "if(temp.compareTo(temp2) >= 0)".

The error is saying "incompatible types: java.lang.Comparable cannot be converted to T".

I think is the problem is when I am typecasting the object

Comment: Please show us the rest of the class and also how you're calling this function.

Comment: ok added more code to it.

Comment: `T` is never defined as Comparable. And so your list isn't necessarily holding Comparable objects

Comment: @Laiman please do **not** edit the code by removing most of it...

Comment: it works for temp but doesnt work for temp2

Comment: `implements DoubleLinkedListADT` - what is `DoubleLinkedListADT` ? please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: @alfasin Thats just an interface

Comment: @alfasin I did not remove anything. Just formatted two lines of code. The code am seeing now and that which was there are totally different.

Comment: @Laiman probably because the OP updated the code while you were editing it...

Comment: @alfasin Yes that might be it. Not editing it again though

Answer (score 1):

First you must alter the declaration of `DoubleLinkedList`to

```
class DoubleLinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

so the compiler knows that `T` is a `Comparable<T>` and can ensure that whatever parameter class you provide will be guaranteed to have a `compareTo()` method.

Then, you don't need the temporaries, since `T` implements `Comparable<T>` you just compare the `T` instances directly:

```
while(curr != null && curr2 != null){
    if(curr.info.compareTo(curr2.info) >= 0){
      return false;
    }
    curr = curr.next;
    curr2 = curr2.next;
}
```

Not sure why you thought you needed to cast to `Comparable<T>`.  Note that the definition of `Comparable<T>.compareTo` is

```
int compareTo​(T o);
```

and not

```
int compareTo​(Comparable<T> o)
```

You commented:

> I added the extends Comparable but it was conflicting with my interface, and i didnt want to change my interface because this was for an assignment.

You have a conflict alright, but it's between the definition of the interface and the requirements of the assignment.  You have added behavior into the list's `equals()` method that depends on an ordering comparison between contained elements.  If this is truly part of the required behavior, then the interface type parameter `T` MUST be declared `<T implements Comparable<T>>` to enforce type safety.  Consider what will happen when you instantiate a `DoubleLinkedList` where an ordering comparison is not meaningful for objects of the type parameter, for example

```
DoubleLInkedList<Map<String,Integer>> list = new DoubleLinkedList<>();
```

If you can implement the desired behavior in terms solely of `equals()` then you'd be OK omitting the type constraint. Otherwise you are giving up the type safety that generics were designed to provide, and the design is broken.

Comment: Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method compareTo(T)
  location: variable info of type T

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include changing the definition of `T` to `T extends Comparable<T>`. Updated.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing the int compareTo​(T o); .  I added the extends Comparable<T> but it was conflicting with my interface, and i didnt want to change my interface because this was for an assignment. But what i did is instead of creating a comparable temp2 for curr2, i just did temp.compareTo(curr2.info) <= 0 . and the sign should have been <= instead of >=. sorry about that. But thanks again

Comment: or better yet, `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`